# How to fix the position of a tableview cell on the top of the view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a table view containing a segmentController as one of its cells. What I want to do is when I scroll up the table view, this segmentController is fixed on the top of the view as the content goes up, rather than disappear.

Comment: is the segemented control on inside of the first cell? it would be easier not to make it part of the cell to be honest, but instead add it outside of the tableview

Comment: Hi, meda. No, it's not the first cell. I have A image view in the fist cell. And I want the segment cell stop scrolling when it reaches the upper margin of the view.

Comment: have you consider adding a different view that will hold that controll? this way you wont need to deal with the tableView

Comment: I found the solution :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894227/uitableview-how-to-keep-table-rows-fixed-as-user-scrolls