# Fixed the position of first cell in the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a dynamic `UITableViewCell`. Now my problem is in some cases I wanted to have the `cell` to be fixed, the `cell` should be in top position, while other cells keeps scrolling under it.

[image: Normal table view]

This `UITableView` is normal case, every cell should be scrollable here.

But,

[image: Table View which first cell should be fixed in the position]

In this `UITableView`, the first cell should be fixed.

PS. the `cell` which will going to be fixed is always present at the top of the `UITableView`.

I did tried with the `viewForHeaderInSection:`, But that did not worked for me, as the cell is generated dynamically and each cell again have a `collectionView` in them, which will provide data form strength and price.

I also tried `scrollViewDidScroll` and the cell is fixed, but get replaced by the next cell as soon as it get's disappear. For `scrollViewDidScroll` I looked and try to implement as suggested in this thread: [UITableView - How to keep table rows fixed as user scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894227/uitableview-how-to-keep-table-rows-fixed-as-user-scrolls)

Comment: Problem in your code not in ui just share your tableview code.

Comment: @RB1509 I am searching for the way to implement it, As I have no idea how to do that. So, I am sharing my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom cell as your header section

For example:

```
- (UIView )tableView:(UITableView )tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     customHeaderSection *headerCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

     return commentCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom header, implement the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method in your table view `delegate` and return the view for your `header`.You will have to manage sections and rows instead of just rows.

Comment: Yea I got that, but Can I generate a header in section, which will have exact properties of the cell ? As it also needs to have a collection view within itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693901/design-uitableviews-section-header-in-interface-builder